# Carousel de Bootstrap -- Cómo puedo hacer para que el botón de "Prev" y "Next" desaparezcan si no hay mas contenido al final o al comienzo

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Tengo la siguiente página (es un proyecto solo para tablet, así que solo funciona adecuando la resolución de pantalla desde el navegador para tablet)

http://www.brendameneses.hostingmyself.com/project3

como pueden observar hay un botón para cada "slide principal" y dentro de cada uno de ellos hay otro slider que en este caso es el carousel de bootstrap. La idea seria que si por ejemplo accedo a uno de los temas y veo el primer item del carousel no se muestre el botón de "prev" si continuo con la navegación, que se muestren los dos (prev y next) y que si llego al ultimo item solo se muestre el de "Prev".

intente con un

```
if ($("#bg_02").hasClass("active")) {
        $(".left carousel-control").css("display","none");
    }
```

Pero no funciono.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la documentación lo mencionan:
http://bxslider.com/examples/manual-show-without-infinite-loop

En la parte de

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  infiniteLoop: false,
  hideControlOnEnd: true
});
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias! pero no es de bxSlider sino  de Carousel de Bootstrap,sabes como podria hacerlo con el carousel?

Comment: Mmm, necesitas checar bien tu código entonces, por que en 'http://www.brendameneses.hostingmyself.com/project3/js/functions.js' tienes el bx-slider, dentro tienes un craousel, necesitas usar uno u otro, el código es algo confuso, sería mejor que crearas un ejemplo con el código mínimo para reproducir el problema